# Pipe stdout of two programs to each other

Tags: linux, bash, redirection, io

I have two programs, one of them prints something first, they need to communicate with each other with their standard IO.

Is there a way in Bash to pipe stdout of two programs to each other? I know I could do this in C with forks and dups, but is there a way with pure Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a named FIFO that will "loop" the pipe:

```
mkfifo myfifo
<myfifo program1 | program2 >myfifo
rm myfifo
```

Even if none of the programs prints anything first, you can "inject" data into the FIFO, so it's received by `program1`:

```
# from another console
echo start >myfifo
```

To observe/store the communication, use `tee` in the right place(s). Examples:

```
<myfifo program1 | program2 | tee myfifo
<myfifo program1 | tee /dev/tty ./log1 | program2 | tee ./log2 >myfifo
```

The whole thing will work in `sh`, there's nothing specific to Bash in this solution.

Please read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193449/108618) about possible scenarios leading to a deadlock.