# bash server that can communicate both ways with remote client

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to do a simple server in bash with netcat that accepts commands from remote machine and returns some data back, I know that other languages are better suited for this task but I am trying to figure out the best way to do this in bash.

So the requirements are:

- listen for incoming connections (no need to handle multiple connections at the same time)
- process commands received from remote machine one line at the time
- return output for each command to the remote machine
- be able to terminate the connection from server side

I have created something that works and meets all the requirements, but it uses temporary file to store the requests and `tail` to read them back. I have been trying for a while now to achieve the same results using only pipes and input/output redirection, or maybe a FIFO, but no luck so far, so I wanted to ask if maybe someone knows some trick that would work here.

My current code (that uses `tail` and temporary file, both of witch I would like to avoid):

```
#!/bin/bash
request=/tmp/bashsrvR

function HandleCommand {
  echo "received command: $1"
  [ "$1" = "exit" ] && return 1
  return 0
}

while :; do
  >$request
  tail -f $request 2>/dev/null | while read line; do
    HandleCommand $line || break
  done | nc -l -c -p 5000 >$request
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIFO is a [solution](https://superuser.com/a/1464329/432690). This is your code modified in a quick and dirty fashion:

```
#!/bin/sh
request=/tmp/bashsrvR
rm "$request"
mkfifo "$request"

HandleCommand () {
  echo "received command: $1"
  [ "$1" = "exit" ] && return 1
  return 0
}

while :; do
  while read line; do
    HandleCommand "$line" || break
  done <"$request" | nc -l -p 5000 >"$request"
done
```

There's nothing here `sh` cannot do, so I used it instead of `bash`, for portability. And I [quoted right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618).

The script detects `exit` but the `nc` server and/or the client may not exit immediately. There are [different implementations of `nc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368160/108618). I tested with traditional (not BSD) `nc` in Debian. I used `nc` as the server and a client. Then running the server with `-q 1` caused an interactive client (i.e. `nc` reading from tty) to terminate just after sending `exit`. In general the behavior depends on the client as well. Compare [BSD `nc` does not terminate on EOF](https://serverfault.com/a/905462).

In my opinion [`socat` is a better tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/549505/108618) as a server in similar cases:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:5000,fork EXEC:'/path/to/inner_script',stderr,pty,echo=0
```

Here the `inner_script` should just read from its stdin, write to its stdout and simply exit when done. The script should not care about network connection, this is the `socat`'s job. Your code reduced to the following snippet can act as an `inner_script`:

```
#!/bin/sh

HandleCommand () {
  echo "received command: $1"
  [ "$1" = "exit" ] && return 1
  return 0
}

while read line; do
  HandleCommand "$line" || exit
done
```

`socat` handles connections *and pipes*; your original problem with redirections is solved automatically. Run `socat` from an outer script and keep the `inner_script` as a separate file.

Note `fork` allows `socat` to serve to many clients, so it acts as the outer `while` loop from your original code. But `fork` also allows `socat` to serve to many clients *simultaneously*. You may or may not want this.

Comment: I never used `socat` and it looks like it is much better suited for my purpose than `nc`, it is even already present on my router that will be running this.Thanks you very much for an exhaustive answer and for your time, you are awesome :)