# Circular pipe in bash

Tags: bash, pipe, exec

I need a circular pipe in Bash.

This doesn’t work:

```
exec 3>&1 | socat | awk | socat >&3  #exec 3>&1
```

This works:

```
exec 3> /dev/stderr ; echo test >&3
```

Can somebody provide the correct syntax for the first example that doesn’t work?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Something like this? [*Pipe stdout of two programs to each other*](https://superuser.com/q/1464326/432690)

Comment: `exec 3>(cat)` also wrong, how can I pipe that 3rd pipe into a programm?

Comment: The answer for Kamil is yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipe stdout of two programs to each other](https://superuser.com/questions/1464326/pipe-stdout-of-two-programs-to-each-other)

Comment: Using mkfifo is more overhead, I wonder why that exec n can't be somehow piped to a process but redirected to a file only.